# Does the use #ifndef and #define change the memory allocation?

Tags: c

I recently saw a header file with such defines:

```
#ifndef DEFINE_ME
#define DEFINE_ME     1
     char abc[10];
#endif
```

but I also found that DEFINE_ME was never defined in any other header file of the project so why was #ifndef used? does it have to do any thing with memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's include guard.

The purpose of This is to prevent multiple declaration of variable.

ifndef = if not defined.
then define it..
if defined then use the previous declaration ..

suppose u have two header files

header1:

```
#ifndef DEFINE_ME
#define DEFINE_ME     1
#endif
```

header 2:

```
#ifndef DEFINE_ME
#define DEFINE_ME     1

#endif
```

now if in c file header 2 is included first then it will include the value from header 2 not from header 1.. as it is already defined in header 2

You can have header file guard also as explained below:

Header1.h

```
#ifndef _header1
#define _header1
#ifndef VAR1
#ifdef VAR1   5
#endif
#endif
```

Header2.h

```
#ifndef _header2
#define _header2
#ifndef VAR1
#ifdef VAR1   5
#endif
#endif
```

Now you have used a guard so that u by mistake include same header in different files of same project then also u will be safe.

Comment: This is nice to explain my problem, see there is no such header1 file ok.

And don't forget the char abc[10]; ?

that is the only thing present in the file which is used later.

Comment: Ok no header1 ... but its for the safety purpose to avoid multiple values of a single variable

Comment: And does it affect the memory allocation??

Comment: Memory will be allocated on the basis of loading of header files..when header files are loaded memory is allocated to the variables..now if the guard is there..then it will prevent the allocation of the memory to variable.which was previously defined

Answer (score 2):

It's called an [`include guard`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

The purpose of `DEFINE_ME` is to prevent the particular (where it's defined) header file being included multiple times accidentally.

---

To understand how it works, try without include guard:

header.h:

```
int x = 5;
```

file.c:

```
#include "header.h"
#include "header.h"

int main() {
   printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

and then try with an include guard:

header.h:

```
#ifndef DEFINE_ME
#define DEFINE_ME 1

int x = 5;

#endif
```

file.c:

```
#include "header.h"
#include "header.h"

int main() {
   printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

When you have `DEFINE_ME`, the header will be included the first time in `fil.c`, the `header.h` is included as `DEFINE_ME` wasn't defined before. But the next `#include "header.h"` wouldn't include the contents of the guard as `DEFINE_ME` has already been defined by the previous inclusion.

Comment: I know that, but it was not defined any were except in this header file. No case of multiple.

Comment: Because the purpose is to prevent _this_ header file from being included multiple times.

Comment: Multiple include of the header file or multiple declaration of the variable DEFINE_ME???

Comment: You can have both with the help of ifndef

Comment: @TusharSharma Imagine you include the file twice in a row. Then the first inclusion will define DEFINE_ME and also define abc. The second inclusion will do neither because DEFINE_ME is already defined.

Comment: @TusharSharma The name `DEFINE_ME` or what value it has, has no significance other than preventing the *same* header file being included accidentally.

Comment: @TusharSharma I have added a simple example illustrating the workings of it. Hopefully, it becomes clear. I also suggest reading the link in the answer first.

Comment: @TusharSharma it's to be able to produce robust code in the future and good practice. If someone continues to develop the code/library containing this header, they can be sure that this file will not be unnecessarily included should the part they're developing now need to include this file.